# ARP reply not working with linux bridge on virtualbox VMs

Tags: virtual-machine

[Please check this Topology diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fkk6.jpg)

I have created 2 virtualbox VMs using ubuntu 16.04.4 TLS, call them VM1 and VM2.

I am running two containers on VM1, call them VM1-C1 and VM1-C2.
I am running two containers on VM2, call them VM2-C1 and VM2-C2.

VM1 and VM2 are connected directly using internal-network(vagrant has option).
Now, I need to steer traffic from VM1-C1 to VM2-C1 and then to internet via linux bridges.
And steer traffic from VM1-C2 to VM2-C2 and then to internet via linux bridges.

Is it possible to achieve this using linux bridges?
I created veth pairs [if1, if3], [if2, if4], [if5, if7], [if6, if8], [if9, if11], [if10, if12] to achieve this(I'll think of any optimizations or you can suggest me better options).

I configured IPs on if1 and if7 from subnet 192.16.1.0/24.
I configured IPs on if2 and if8 from subnet 192.16.2.0/24.

When I try to ping if7(192.16.1.10) from if1(192.16.1.1), I see the arp is reaching if7 and ARP reply is seen at eth0 of VM2.
But ARP reply is not seen at eth0 of VM1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.